# Find unique element values and create/mark a node with group number

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

Let me explain this again.

For example if we have a db table, we query for some columns and adds up all values in those columns to make a unique key and save it a new columns and update that another new columns with a number. Loop again and if again the combination of other column values is duplicate with previous one then update the 2nd column with same value as previous number otherwise next sequence number. I have to do it in a xml file.

e-g.

```
Combinatin of 
values from 
different nodes        Value
---------------       --------
A-B-C-D-E               1
A-B-C-D-F               2
A-B-C-D-G               3
A-B-C-D-E               1



    namespace XMLdemo2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// will use this dictionary object to store and compare node values
            Dictionary<String, String> Rxml = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        String rdsName = "";
        String rdrValue = "";

        using (XmlReader reader = mlReader.Create(@"C:\Development\XML\Batch1823.xml"))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            reader.ReadToFollowing("Machine");
                            reader.MoveToAttribute("machineId");
                            rdsName = reader.Name;
                            rdrValue = reader.Value;
                            sb.Append(rdsName).Append("=").Append(rdrValue);

                            reader.ReadToFollowing("Rod");
                            reader.MoveToAttribute("finalReference");
                            rdsName = reader.Name;
                            rdrValue = reader.Value;
                            sb.Append(rdsName).Append("=").Append(rdrValue);

                            reader.MoveToAttribute("color");
                            rdsName = reader.Name;
                            rdrValue = reader.Value;
                            sb.Append(rdsName).Append("=").Append(rdrValue);

                            reader.MoveToAttribute("length");
                            rdsName = reader.Name;
                            rdrValue = reader.Value;
                            sb.Append(rdsName).Append("=").Append(rdrValue);

                            reader.ReadToFollowing("Piece");
                            reader.MoveToAttribute("angle");
                            rdsName = reader.Name;
                            rdrValue = reader.Value;
                            sb.Append(rdsName).Append("=").Append(rdrValue);

                            reader.MoveToAttribute("angleA");
                            rdsName = reader.Name;
                            rdrValue = reader.Value;
                            sb.Append(rdsName).Append("=").Append(rdrValue);

                            reader.MoveToAttribute("angleB");
                            rdsName = reader.Name;
                            rdrValue = reader.Value;
                            sb.Append(rdsName).Append("=").Append(rdrValue);

                            reader.ReadToFollowing("Operations");
                            if (reader.ReadToDescendant("Operation"))
                            {
                                do
                                {
                                    reader.MoveToAttribute("name");
                                    rdsName = reader.Name;
                                    rdrValue = reader.Value;
                                    sb.Append(rdsName).Append("=").Append(rdrValue);

                                    reader.MoveToAttribute("X");
                                    rdsName = reader.Name;
                                    rdrValue = reader.Value;
                                    sb.Append(rdsName).Append("=").Append(rdrValue);
                                } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("Operation"));
                            }

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

This program reading all values but how to write it at the same time to the same xml file based on this values. My guess is to save this combination of node values in a Dictionary object as key and compare the Stringbuilder sb value with it. if found in dictionary then do not create new item in dictionary but get the value of dictionary and update in xml but how? please help.

Thanks

QF

Answer (score 0):

OK finally I got my solution using XmlDocument. Still trying to find another solution using LINQ to xml.

Here it is.

```
        static void Test(String _xmlFilename)
    {
        //string _path = @"C:\Development\XML\Batch1823.xml";
        String _path = _xmlFilename;

        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        Dictionary<string, int> _marks = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        int _markCounter = 0;
        xDoc.Load(_path);

        foreach(XmlNode xRod in xDoc.SelectNodes("/ProductionLot/ProductionSet/Machine/Rod"))
        {
            String _finalRef = xRod.Attributes.GetNamedItem("finalReference").Value;
            String _color = xRod.Attributes.GetNamedItem("color").Value;

            foreach (XmlNode xPiece in xRod.SelectNodes("Piece"))
            {
                String _length = xPiece.Attributes.GetNamedItem("length").Value;
                String _angle = xPiece.Attributes.GetNamedItem("angle").Value;
                String _angleA = xPiece.Attributes.GetNamedItem("angleA").Value;
                String _angleB = xPiece.Attributes.GetNamedItem("angleB").Value;
                String _operStr = "";

                foreach (XmlNode xOper in xPiece.SelectNodes("Operations/Operation"))
                {
                    String _operName = xOper.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value;
                    String _operXPos = xOper.Attributes.GetNamedItem("X").Value;
                    _operStr = _operStr + "//" + _operName + ":" + _operXPos;
                }

                String _pieceMark = _finalRef + "/" + _color + "/" + _length + "/" + _angle + "/" + _angleA + "/" + "/" + _operStr + "/" + _angleB;
                String _markID = "0";

                if (!_marks.ContainsKey(_pieceMark))
                {
                    _markCounter += 1;
                    _marks.Add(_pieceMark, _markCounter);
                    _markID = _markCounter.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    _markID = _marks[_pieceMark].ToString();
                }

                xPiece.Attributes.Append(xDoc.CreateAttribute("group")).Value = _markID;
            }
        }

        xDoc.Save(_path);
    }
```

So we can change the node names here according to our need. But my problem is done successfully.

Enjoy....!